# Access the value of children passed from the Router to the form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

The important part of my code looks like.

Routes:

```
<Route path="/login" component="Login">
    <Route path="/login/lender" component="LenderLogin"/>
    <Route path="/login/customer" component="CustomerLogin"/>
</Route>
```

Render inside Login:

```
<div>
    <form>
    {/*All my common inputs*/}
    {/*Link to Customer and Lender*/}

    {this.props.children}
    <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

CustomerLogin and LenderLogin has their own inputs inside them. On submitting the form how can I get the `LenderLogin` or `CustomerLogin` data into the`Login`?

Comment: Which mechanism do you use to keep the form values? (you tagged `redux`, so I assume you keep a central state?)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions.

1. In react you can use props to pass data/callbacks. (GOOD)
   you can pass callbacks to child components that can  be called when data
   in child changes.

   For more detail. http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/
2. Use ref (BAD)
   assign attribute ref="customerComponent"  to your customer and  then ref="lenderComponent" to your other one. You can then define methods in those components that return values.
   when desired you can call methods in customComponent.getMyValue() to get values.
   https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should use one component Form inside this. For example:

*my_component.js*

```
import FormComponent from './form_component';

class MyComponent extends React {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <FormComponent data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

*form_component.js*

```
const FormComponent = ({data}) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <form>
        ...
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FormComponent;
```

But if you prefer to use children, you can use IndexRoute

```
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

<Route path="/login/lender" component="LenderLogin">
  <IndexRoute component={FormComponent)} />
<Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using state manager like Redux, you should store data from your `LenderLogin` or `CustomerLogin` there (via dispatching event), and then retrieve it within `Login` component(with `connect()` method from `react-redux` library.